# WMIC to a different network

Tags: networking, command-line, remote, windows-server-2012-r2, wmic

I am trying to run a command on that will execute on Server2 from Server1 using WMIC

e.g: from Server1 run the following command to execute on server2

```
WMIC /node:Server2 process call create "cmd.exe /c mycommand"
```

The issue is that Server1 and Server2 are on different networks

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the problem? Are you able to connect to server 2 at all? If so see `wmic /user /?` and `wmic /password /?`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Server1 can access Server2, meaning there is a route
between the two computers, use the IP address of Server2, rather than
its name.

The computer name is not recognized across networks.

Comment: I received the following error: ERROR:
Description = The RPC server is unavailable.  RPC services are enabled and running automatically.  I have just ping the server2 now and I get time outs... I guess that is the issue...

Comment: This probably means that the computer has no route to the other network.